# How to read sound change transcriptions?

Tags: phonology, language-change, sound-change, transcription, spe

https://chridd.nfshost.com/diachronica/
I don't understand what most of these transcriptions mean. I only know what *#, #*, and _x mean.

Comment: Hi, as it is this question is a bit too broad to really answer. If you could narrow it down a bit, e.g. by providing a few example rules you're struggling to understand, that would help us give you an answer

Answer (score 1):

The notation is  called [SPE style notation](https://brianwilliamsmith.github.io/teaching/401_2.html) because it is inspired by *The Sound Patterns of English* by Chomsky and Halle.

The link above gives full details, here I will sketch the main points:

- BEFORE → AFTER / CONTEXT
  The starting point comes first, than an arrow, than the outcome of the sound change. Optional is a context that determines the sound change, when it is left out, it is unconditioned, or at least general enough to enumerate the exceptions otherwise.
- Special symbol _ is a placeholder for the sound to change. The condition can occur before that sound, after it, or on both sides
- Special symbol # means word boundary
- The emptyset sign Ø (or some similar symbol) denotes the absence of a sound in rules where a sound emerges from nothing or gets deleted
- Curly braces {m,n} denote enumerations
- Capital letters denote classes of sounds: V any vowel, C any consonant, N any nasal consonant. For a list of capital letters used in the *Index Diachronica*, see the [Key to Abbreviations](https://chridd.nfshost.com/diachronica/all#Abbreviations) there. Note that capital letters are sometimes assigned *ad hoc* to fit some specific needs (e.g., in the section on Uralic languages, A, O, and U have special meanings explained at the start of that section)
- You can have features in angular brackets, like [-voiced] for voicelessness.

Answer (score 0):

These are letters of the International Phonetic Alphabet. You can see their definitions and hear what they sound like [here](https://web.uvic.ca/ling/resources/ipa/charts/IPAlab/IPAlab.htm). The rule notation is simple: "()" means "whether or not ... is present" and {a,b,c} beanc "a or b or c"